# Python BeautifulSoup changes behaviour when provided string in findall()

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I need to find some code tags with string , while find_all by tagname will successfully find all code tags, when i use a string method it weardly wont find all code tags.Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

text = """<!-- Data starts here -->
<code>LGEL 281220Z 33010G20KT CAVOK 32/11 Q1013</code><br/>
<br/><code>TAF LGEL 281100Z 2812/2912 34018G28KT 9999 FEW020 <br/>  BECMG 2816/2818 34015KT <br/>  TEMPO 2909/2912 34015G25KT</code><br/>
<hr width="65%"/>
<!-- Data ends here -->"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')

info = soup.find_all("code")
value = soup.find_all('code',string = re.compile('LGEL'))

print(value)#This will not find second code tag
print(info)#This finds all code tags successfully
```

Comment: It is working fine for me, please try to reproduce any error if you get

Comment: It works but they have different outputs that it shouldnt.value is mising the second <code> tag.

Comment: Can you clarify your expected output?

Comment: I expect value output to be the same as info output but Mazz example still gives diferrent outputs

Comment: I think @Maaz solution is giving right solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While an answer is provided that helps the the developer move on, I believe the question of why still remains. This can actually be answered by referencing BeautifulSoup's documentation. Particularly here: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-string-argument.

I that section explains when using `string="some text"` in a `find`/`find_all` that it finds tags whose `.string` property matches.

The `.string` property is described here: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string. It essentially states that `.string` only returns something if its only child is text.

So the reason it doesn't work in every `code` tag is because some code tags have more that just text. In your case `br` tags. Providing your own filter will actually get you what you want:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

text = """<!-- Data starts here -->
<code>LGEL 281220Z 33010G20KT CAVOK 32/11 Q1013</code><br/>
<br/><code>TAF LGEL 281100Z 2812/2912 34018G28KT 9999 FEW020 <br/>  BECMG 2816/2818 34015KT <br/>  TEMPO 2909/2912 34015G25KT</code><br/>
<hr width="65%"/>
<!-- Data ends here -->"""

my_pattern = re.compile('LGEL')

def my_filter(tag):
    """Filter the tag."""

    return tag.name == 'code' and my_pattern.search(tag.get_text()) is not None


soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
value = soup.find_all(my_filter)

print(value)#This will not find second code tag
```

Output

```
[<code>LGEL 281220Z 33010G20KT CAVOK 32/11 Q1013</code>, <code>TAF LGEL 281100Z 2812/2912 34018G28KT 9999 FEW020 <br/>  BECMG 2816/2818 34015KT <br/>  TEMPO 2909/2912 34015G25KT</code>]
```

I believe this answers the why showing how to work around it.

Comment: I ended up replacing <br/> before using soup , but your answer works like a charm

Answer (score 4):

You have to first [extract()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#extract) the `br` tags, they are breaking the html structure. Then your code will work.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

text = """<!-- Data starts here -->
<code>LGEL 281220Z 33010G20KT CAVOK 32/11 Q1013</code><br/>
<br/><code>TAF LGEL 281100Z 2812/2912 34018G28KT 9999 FEW020  <br/>  BECMG 2816/2818 34015KT  <br/>  TEMPO 2909/2912 34015G25KT</code><br/>
<hr width="65%"/>
<!-- Data ends here -->"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
for br in soup.find_all('br'):
    br.extract()

info = soup.find_all("code")
value = soup.find_all('code', string = re.compile('LGEL'))

print(value)#This will not find second code tag
print(info)#This finds all code tags successfully
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[<code>LGEL 281220Z 33010G20KT CAVOK 32/11 Q1013</code>, <code>TAF LGEL 281100Z 2812/2912 34018G28KT 9999 FEW020   BECMG 2816/2818 34015KT   TEMPO 2909/2912 34015G25KT</code>]
[<code>LGEL 281220Z 33010G20KT CAVOK 32/11 Q1013</code>, <code>TAF LGEL 281100Z 2812/2912 34018G28KT 9999 FEW020   BECMG 2816/2818 34015KT   TEMPO 2909/2912 34015G25KT</code>]
```

Comment: i can't get your output , i dont know hyw where do you use br.extract?

Comment: i cant understand why but for me it works only if replace <br/> with <br> before the second <code> tag, can i do this by code?

Comment: Dude you changed the text , anyway thx for help i replace </br> and works fine

Comment: @ΕυάγγελοςΓρηγορόπουλος sorry that whas for my tests, but it work with anywayn I edit. If you want to keep the struct, you can loop an your info list and apply a regex on each term (after an extract). You are welcome :-)